# A question on isomorphism of quotient vector spaces and equality of dimension of kernel and codimension of range

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, operator-theory

This is a question I encountered in my linear algebra and functional analysis class.

> Let $ T : U \rightarrow U $ be a linear transformation where the vector spaces are not necessarily finite-dimensional. I know that we have the isomorphism $U/ \ker(T) \cong \text{ran}(T)$ so that if the dimensions of the cokernel and range are finite, one has equality of dimensions. Can I also deduce $\ker(T) \cong U/\text{ran}(T)$? I basically only need equality of dimension of kernel and codimension of range when these are finite.

Can anyone show me how to prove $\dim(\ker(T)) = \text{codim} \; \text{ran}(T)$ when these are finite but $U$ may be infinite-dimensional? I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false in the infinite-dimensional case. For example, take $T_L : \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to be the left shift

$$T_L(a_1, a_2, \dots) = (a_2, a_3, \dots).$$

Then $\dim \text{ker}(T_L) = 1$ but $\text{codim } \text{im}(T_L) = 0$.

In general the left shift and the right shift

$$T_R(a_1, a_2, \dots) = (0, a_1, a_2, \dots)$$

are the first counterexamples you should look at in infinite-dimensional linear algebra. For example the right shift $T_R$ satisfies $\dim \text{ker}(T_R) = 0$ but $\text{codim } \text{im}(T_R) = 1$. It also famously has no eigenvalues (unlike the left shift).

Comment: thank you so much. Here is a question I have asked and got an answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850619/proving-dim-keri-t-dim-keri-t-infty-for-finite-rank-operator-on-a-hil/3850776#3850776

Comment: the author of the answer says the dimension of the kernel of $I-T$ is equal to the codimension of the range of $I-T$ for $T:U-U$ where $T$ is finite-rank, i.e has finite-dimensional range.

Comment: can you please help me understand it?

Comment: @kroner: the author uses the fact that $I - T$ is a Fredholm operator of Fredholm index zero (because $I$ has Fredholm index $0$ and $I - T$ is a compact perturbation of it which preserves the Fredholm index): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator

Comment: I get that it is Fredholm but how do we deduce that the index is zero? The index zero is what I do not understand that is why I came to the false conclusion I asked about here. Thank you.

Comment: @kroner: it's a general fact about Fredholm operators that adding a compact operator doesn't change the index, so $I - T$ has the same index as $I$, which is $0$. Although admittedly I don't know how to prove this off the top of my head. I would just argue directly in this case, probably.

Comment: thank you this makes much more sense now. Any hint you can give me how to directly prove index zero in this case? Just a hint in the direction of a proof that I can build on. Thanks for a wonderful answer.

Comment: @kroner: you can work it out in coordinates by writing $T = \sum \sigma_i u_i \otimes v_i^{\ast}$ but it's not particularly enlightening. I don't know off the top of my head if there's a nicer way.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking of showing a linear bijection between $\ker(I-T)$ and $H / \text{ran}(I-T)$, Do you think that would work? I am not sure how to  work it out with coordinates, it seems awfully long and tedious even if we take the coordinates to be orthonormal like in the canonical form for finite-rank operators.

Comment: @kroner: maybe you can make it work but I don't know how to. If you work out in coordinates what it means for a vector to be in $\text{ker}(I - T)$ and again what it means for a vector to be in $\text{ker}(I - T^{\ast})$ you'll see that the problem reduces to the finite-dimensional case, basically. Probably there's a nicer way to do it but I don't know it.

Comment: thank you very much, very helpful